is there difference between 소게 and 속에
I recently started to read short stories to enhance my vocabulary and and to understand the spelling. These two words 소게 and 속에 I know have different meanings but if someone says write "soge" how should I know which one it is? If there is a trick please let me know it will be helpful. Thank You.

there is no trick. You need to know by context

속에 sounds morw like soke and 소게 ls more of a soge

소게/속에 have different sounds.
마음속에 있는 말.
내 친구 소게할게
It sounds diffrent.
but I don't know foreigner could differentiate it.
